# How to prevent a Visual Studio Code extension from running on certain file extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using an extension to work with `.vue` files. However, I noticed the extension is causing problems in `.ts` and `.js` files.

I need this extension so I can't just disable it. **Can I prevent an extension from running or affecting a specific set of file extensions?**

Ideally, I would disable/disallow the extension on `.ts` and `.js` files and keep it for `.vue` files.

Is it possible to achieve this with some vscode settings, or is the only way to do this to ask the extension maker to release a fix to the extension themselves?

Comment: https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues

Comment: What's the name of this extension?

Comment: @Ammar The extension was Volar. But, I was just wondering if it was possible in vscode to control the file types any generic extension can run on. It seems not (since nobody suggested otherwise), but thankfully the team at Volar fixed the issue.